# Handling both 301 redirects and internal rewriting in .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to do three things on my website:

- Redirect users with a 301 to the HTTPS version of the site when they access the HTTP version
- Redirect users with a 301 to the "no-www" version of the site when they put a `www` in the url
- Silently (or internally) redirect `/*` to `/index.php?p=*` (as I am using a framework). (Or even, redirect "visually" `/index.php?p=*` to `/*`, then internally redirect `/*` to `/index.php?p=*` ...)

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

However when I am running this configuration, my 301 redirects are not working – more precisely, a 301 code is *actually* sent to the client, but no `Location:` header is sent:

```
$ curl http://mywebsite.com/path -I
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 19:03:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Set-Cookie: ci_session=q24j0enjrskagec2fggi256bpg5fsvs6; expires=Thu, 23-Apr-2020 20:39:57 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

If I try to put the block about `index.php` before the two other ones, the HTTPS and `www` redirection work, but the `Location:` header has a weird behavior when dealing with pages:

```
λ curl http://mywebsite.com/fr/salon -I
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 19:09:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Location: https://mywebsite.com/fr/salon?p=fr/salon
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

(You can also see the charset changed, for some weird reason)

What are the changes I must make to my rules to make my three redirections work?
Thank you!

Comment: These results may be caused by the Apache configuration.  .htaccess should be a last resort solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
> ```

You are missing the `L` (`last`) flag on both of your redirects. Without the `L` flag processing continues and is getting caught by the internal rewrite that follows.

For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:** You should strictly include the `L` flag on your later rewrite as well. Although if this is the last `RewriteRule` anyway then it doesn't strictly matter. However, if you later add more rules then it could be important.

> Or even, redirect "visually" `/index.php?p=*` to `/*`

This part is only strictly required if you are changing an existing URL structure where the *old* `index.php?p=` URL is indexed by search engines or linked to by third parties.

The important point here is to avoid a potential redirect loop by preventing the rewritten URL being redirected. We can do this by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable (which is empty on the initial request and set to "200", as in 200 OK HTTP status after the the first successful rewrite).

For example, *before* your existing redirects, immediately after the `RewriteBase` directive, you could do something like the following to externally redirect `/index.php?p=*` to `/*`:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://example.com/%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag (Apache 2.4+) is necessary in order to remove the query string (ie `p=*` URL parameter) from the request. This does assume you have no other URL parameters that need to be passed through - they are all discarded.

This also assumes that the `p` URL param always occurs at the start of the query string (as per your rewrite).

By including the absolute URL in the *substitution* string we avoid any secondary redirect associated with requesting HTTP or www subdomain.

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. It is preferable to first test with a 302, before changing to a 301 (permanent) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: The thing is, if I put a `L` flag on both redirects and if I need *both* of them (in the case of a `www` in the URL AND a non-HTTPS connection), will the second be applied? Well, in this case it seems the first manages the HTTPS redirect as well, but I am curious to know what I should do if I need to apply two redirects.
And I also need the internal rewrite - so wouldn't putting `L` affect that as well?

Comment: You never need _both_ redirects for the same initial request - as you say, the first rule (www to non-www) redirects to HTTPS as well. There is only, at most, one redirect here. The internal rewrite only occurs when the redirects don't - that is correct. The purpose of the redirects are to canonicalize the request - this must be done and finished before the internal rewrite occurs. (An external redirect triggers an entirely separate request - hence the need for the `L` flag.)

Comment: I've updated my answer addressing the missing `L` flag on your rewrite and your additional "requirement"(?) to canonicalise/redirect a request of the form `/index.php?p=*` to `/*`. Without the `L` flags, your directives are essentially _conflicting_ with each other, as processing continues through the file and the next directive is triggered.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work correctly with adding L flags now. (The part about "visual" redirection was not a requirement, it was more a bonus, but I guess this will be useful for me at some point). Thank you for the help. However, it seems like the `L` flag only applies to visible redirects? I am surprised the internal redirect still works, even though the URL is already redirected by a rule with the `L` flag in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Does it handle the `index.php?p=` part? It does not look like to.

Comment: Code only answers are not a good fit on StackExchange - please provide some explanation. This is really no different to the code/redirects given in the question, except for the addition of the - all important - `L` flag. @Ailothaen The internal rewrite to `index.php?p=` (as you already have) is still required following the redirect directives.